# Classes in CSS, Could there be numbers in it?

Tags: html, css

How do i arrange my classes in CSS?
How can I add a combination of letters and numbers?

Or what's the best way to have them arranged?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, numbers are allowed. Pretty much anything is allowed. Just know that special characters used by CSS (such as spaces, dots, #, >, etc) will cause errors.

Comment: Alright thanks, but could you just tell me like i have this .first .first2 but won't work :(

Comment: It should work; there must be some other issue.